# How to implement history function?

Tags: c, shell, command-line

I am new to C programming and currently learning this into a course. I'm facing an issues while trying to practice the below history function.

*I'm able to display the shell commands. However, when I type history, the past shell commands are not getting saved into the history buffer.*

Can anyone help me to find where I went wrong?

***Here is my code:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#define BUFSIZE     20  
#define MAX_WORD_IN_LINE 20 

int tokenize(char *str, char **args)
{
    int i, argc = 0;
    char *token;

    token = strtok(str," \t\n");
    for(i=0; token!=NULL;i++)
        {
            args[i] = token;
            printf("args[%d] = %s\n", i, args[i]);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
            argc++;
        }
    return argc;
}

void display_strings(char **p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return;
    while(*p != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",*p);
        p++;
    }
}

int history(char *hist[], int current){
    int i = current;
    int hist_num = 1;

    do {
        if (hist[i]) {
            printf("%4d  %s\n", hist_num, hist[i]);
            hist_num++;
        }

        i = (i + 1) % BUFSIZE;

    } while (i != current);

    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    char *args[MAX_WORD_IN_LINE];
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    char *hist[BUFSIZE];
    int i,current=0;

    pid_t   pid;
    int argc;

    for(i=0;i<BUFSIZE;i++)
        hist[i]= NULL;

    while(1) {
        memset(args,0,MAX_WORD_IN_LINE);
        printf("osh> ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, stdin);
        argc = tokenize(buffer, args);
        //display_strings(args);

        // skip on empty command
        if (argc == 0) continue;

        if (strcmp(args[0],"quit") == 0) break;
        else if (strcmp(args[0], "hello") == 0) printf("Hello there. How are you?\n");
        else if (strcmp(args[0],"history")==0) history(hist,current);
        else {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {

                hist[current]=strdup(args[0]);
                current++;

                execvp(args[0], args);
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Your code ends in the middle of the `main()` function.

Comment: Most of all, *you* can help.  Stick in a few print statements to trace execution path and print out variables at critical processing points.  Most of all, start with prints to track how you add a line to the history buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of the string that `args[0]` points to when you save it in `hist`. Currently, you're just assigning the pointer to the current `args[0]`, and it will be overwritten by the next command. When you print the history, you'll just get the last command repeatedly. So use:

```
hist[current] = strdup(args[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for letting me know this,. i will add the above step